# Is the closure of a set in a surface homeomorphic to the closure of its image under a chart?

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, contact-topology

Consider a surface $\mathfrak S$ and an open set $A \in \mathfrak S$. If $A$ is homeomorphic to an open disc and $\partial A$ is homeomorphic to a circle, does this mean $\overline A$ is necessarily homeomorphic to a closed disc?

Answer (score 1):

Not if $\mathfrak S$ is allowed to have a boundary:
Consider $$\mathfrak S=\{\,(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\mid x^2+y^2<4\land (y\ne 0\lor x\ge -1)\,\}$$ and $$A=\{\,(x,y)\in \mathfrak S\mid x^2+y^2>1\,\}.$$

Comment: Thank you very much! I'm sorry for missing the boundaried case and I edited the question to express my idea clearly.

Comment: Intuitively I can see why $A$ is equivalent to an open disk, but I'm struggling to come up with a homeomorphism. Could you please supply one?

Comment: @[K.Power](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/306685/k-power) $\biggl\{\begin{aligned}&r = r_0 \in (1, 2)\\ &\theta = \theta_0\in (-\tfrac\pi2, \tfrac{3\pi}2)\end{aligned}
\mapsto \biggl\{\begin{aligned}&x = 2r_0-3\\ &y = \frac{\theta_0}\pi - \frac12\end{aligned}$